# Display problem in Ubuntu 12.04 in vmware

Tags: display

I am running on a vmware and observe that a lot of times my text gets cut off as shown in the diagram and there no way I can access this. [image] Can anyone give me some solutions? I have adjusted the resolution but it still doesnt work correctly.